# Table Hover Border Color Remove column lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, hover

I need to fix this table so that the lines above the hovered point are hidden within that column.  Lets say the bottom middle box is hovered you will see 3 lines above it.  I need those lines to not show up.

```
  <table>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </table>


    <script>
      $('td').on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
             $(this).prevAll().addBack()
             .add($(this).parent().prevAll()
             .children(':nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) +   
       ')')).toggleClass('hover');
         });

  </script>

table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
      }
 td {
    border:1px solid black;
 }
.hover {
    border-color:#ef7c32; border-width:2px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This toggle the hover class on a column of cells:

```
  $('td').on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
     var ix = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
     $('table tr').children().eq(ix).toggleClass('hover');
  });
```

The first statement finds the index of the hovered cell within the row. The second toggles the class on the cell at that index in all rows.

Then style accordingly:

```
.hover {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none:
}
table tr:first-child .hover {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:last-child .hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```